# Difference between Global Pooling and (normal) Pooling Layers in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, caffe, theano

Is there any significance difference between the `Pooling` layers. There are two types of Max and Average Pooling ( except 1,2,3-D ) basically named `GlobalPooling` and `(normal)Pooling`. In the documents provided by Keras, there is not so much difference and explanation provided.

What is the difference among the different layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal pooling layers do the pool according to the specific `pool_size`, `stride`, and `padding`. 
For example

```
inp = Input((224, 224, 3))
x = MaxPooling()(x)  # default pool_size and stride is 2
```

The output will has shape `(112, 112, 3)`.

Global pooling is like, make the pool size equal to width and heigth, and do flatten. If input shape is `(224, 224, 3)` you will get a tensor shape `(3)`, if input is `(7, 7, 1024)` you will get a `(1024)` .